# Behaviour of AWS Lambda triggered by schedule function 'rate' with concurrency > 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency, aws-serverless

I need to create a lambda that processes records in a DynamoDB table, which will be triggered by the scheduling function `rate (1 minutes)`. This lambda, depending on the amount data it needs to process, could take anywhere between 1 second and 5 minutes, give or take.

My understanding is that if I set concurrency to 1:

- The lambda will try to trigger every minute
- If the previous lambda instance has not finished (running longer than 1 minute), it will cancel the attempt since an instance is already running, and it will try again a minute later

My question is what happens if I set the concurrency > 1, so for example, 2:

- Will there be 2 lambdas triggered every minute ?
- Or will it trigger 1 lambda every minute, but

  - lambda@minute0 is created and takes 3 minutes
  - lambda@minute1 is also created and take 2 minutes
  - lambda@minute2 will not be created since we already have 2 instances

I will try to answer my own question once I do the tests if there is no answer before that.

Comment: How did it go? Did you tests show some different behavior?

Comment: Hi Marcin, the service will take some time to develop, I will be doing my tests in the following weeks. Thanks for checking in !

Answer (score 2):

It will be **as you describe**, except "Will there be 2 lambdas triggered every minute ?". There can be only two if there is "free" concurrency for that to be consumed. So if you have already two functions running for few minutes, there is no "free" concurrency to start a third function.

Comment: Ok, so on minute 0, lambda1 and lambda2 will be created, and if both take 90 seconds, nothing will happen on minute 1, and on minute 2, 2 lambdas will be created again.
Do you know that from experience ? I couldn't find an answer to this question on the AWS documentation (and sent them a feedback for that purpose).

Comment: @JulianHonma It won't be exactly that because accuracy of CloudWatch rule is 1 minute. So CW event's wont be triggered each minute precisely. The purpose of concurrency is to limit concurrent executions of your function. I don't have a link to how it works exactly with CW events, but I don't think it matters. Concurrency of 2 still applies. Just run your tests as planned. You can inspect CW invocations metrics for your function to verify the behavior.